# GEOSGeom_createLinearRing_r returned a NULL pointer

Tags: python, gdal, shapely, cartopy

I want to import `cartopy` on Python3, but it keeps showing me

```
File "shapely\speedups\_speedups.pyx",
  line 408, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linearring_from_py
  GEOSGeom_createLinearRing_r returned a NULL pointer
```

I've tried reinstalling cartopy, but it won't work at all. Is there something wrong with GDAL or Fiona?

Comment: How did you install those libraries? Which exact versions do you have installed?

Comment: For cartopy, I just use conda install cartopy. And for gdal and fiona, I donwload wheel manually and use pip intall **.whl cause conda can't find suitable version.

Comment: cartopy 0.18.0 ; fiona 1.8.17 ; gdal 3.1.4

Comment: It is a shapely problem, not a cartopy problem

Comment: Try `from shapely import speedups`and after `speedups.disable()`as in  [using qgis and shapely error: GEOSGeom_createLinearRing_r returned a NULL pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62075847/using-qgis-and-shaply-error-geosgeom-createlinearring-r-returned-a-null-pointer)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, solved by changing the order of import statement. If 'rasterio' placed before 'cartopy' this error occurs but nothing happens when change the order.

I foud this solution by comparing 2 programs using cartopy, one works fine which was developed more than 3 months ago and the other developed recently which have the same error. First I tested the solution proposed by using speedups module of shapely although this solution caused the following error.

```
File "C:/Users/go_ta/PyCharm/GIS/test_cartopy.py", line 103, in draw_tsugaru_current
    ax.set_extent([500.66345214843744, 503.99230957031244, 
                  40.55137419871514, 42.65820178455669])
File "C:\Tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py", 
    line 858, in set_extent
    projected = self.projection.project_geometry(domain_in_crs, crs)
File "C:\Tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py", line 201, 
    in project_geometry
    return getattr(self, method_name)(geometry, src_crs)
File "C:\Tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py", line 207, 
    in _project_line_string
      return cartopy.trace.project_linear(geometry, src_crs, self)
File "lib/cartopy/trace.pyx", line 644, in cartopy.trace.project_linear
File "lib/cartopy/trace.pyx", line 78, in 
     cartopy.trace.shapely_from_geos
File "C:\Tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py", 
     line 78, in geom_factory raise ValueError ("No Shapely geometry 
              can be created from null value")
ValueError: No Shapely geometry can be created from null value
```

Then I gave up this solution and came up with the idea of affection of import statements.
I replaced the import statements by the old one then added the missing modules and I found that the program works fine then tried to change the order of import statements handling images.
Then I foud the cause of the above relationships.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to：[pysteps error when installed cartopy](https://github.com/pySTEPS/pysteps/issues/201)